# Как в VisualStudio сделать что-бы свой контрол можно было добавлять на форму

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, webforms

Я сделал контрол наследуемый от ImageButton, он появился в панели элементов, но на форму я его добавить не могу, что я сделал не так, или чего еще нужно сделать?

код моего контрола:

```
public class AddButton : ImageButton
{
    public AddButton():base()
    {
        ImageUrl = "https://ссылка_на_картинку";
        ToolTip = "Добавить";
        AlternateText = "Добавить";
    }
}
```

Замечу что в коде когда добавляю:

```
public MyPanel()
{
     Controls.Add(new AddButton());
}
```

Все как надо добавляется, однако когда использую визуальный редактор, то не могу добавить.
UPD: Забыл сказать что проект ASP.Net WebForms.

Comment: Это смотрели: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537.aspx ?

Comment: *он появился в панели элементов, но на форму я его добавить не могу* - что при этом происходит?

Comment: @Андрей NOP собственно при перетаскивании на панель, курсор меняется на красный перечеркнутый круг

Comment: @АндрейNOP посмотрел msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537.aspx , и как понимаю, я должен что-то еще указать, но что надо указать не понятно.

Comment: Ага, атрибут `ToolboxData` надо установить (и, возможно, `assembly:TagPrefix`). Смотрите по ссылке пример с ними

Comment: Почитай https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features

Comment: Здесь еще http://avidreaders.ru/book/c-razrabotka-komponentov-v-ms-visual.html